# Run time error '14': "Out of string space"

Tags: vba

```
Sub SplitIntoMultipleFile()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim sFile As String  'Name of the original file
Dim sText As Variant  'The file text
Dim lStep As Long    'Max number of lines in the new files
Dim vX        'Variant arrays. vX = input, vY = output
Dim vY
Dim iFile As Integer 'File number from Windows
Dim lCount As Long   'Counter
Dim lIncr As Long    'Number for file name
Dim lMax As Long     'Upper limit for loop
Dim lNb As Long      'Counter
Dim lSoFar As Long   'How far did we get?

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

sFile = "N:\New\RB\Int\2_F_TR02_ICICI_N_10032021_m.csv" 'Application.GetOpenFilename()

If sFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

lStep = 655390

lStep = lStep - 1

sText = _
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sFile).ReadAll
vX = Split(sText, vbLf)

sText = ""

Do While lSoFar < UBound(vX)

   If UBound(vX) - lSoFar >= lStep Then
      ReDim vY(lStep)
      lMax = lStep + lSoFar
   Else
      ReDim vY(UBound(vX) - lSoFar)
      lMax = UBound(vX)
   End If
   
   lNb = 0
   For lCount = lSoFar To lMax
      vY(lNb) = vX(lCount)
      lNb = lNb + 1
   Next

   lSoFar = lCount
   iFile = FreeFile

   lIncr = lIncr + 1
   Open sFile & "-" & lIncr & ".csv" For Output As #iFile
      **Print #iFile, Join(vX, vbCrLf)**
   Close #iFile
Loop

Erase vX
Erase vY

Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Procedure SplitTextFile"
Erase vX
Erase vY


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to split CSV file which is bigger than 500 Mb. The error I am getting Error, **Run time error '14': "Out of string space"**

**Line where I am getting the error is:** Print #iFile, Join(vY, vbCrLf)

I have few restriction on my computer, I cannot use powershell or AccessDb. So I am trying my best to do this with what I know.
Is it possible to do it more efficiently or any other method? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Open one file for reading, read a line at a time and write out to a second file until you hit the line limit, then close that and open another file for writing, etc etc

Comment: Macro willl be running 655390 loops, I just ran it, but the macro just froze. And its been 15 mins and its still running. is there any efficient ways?

Comment: Performance will be optimal if you write to a local drive (like C: for example).  If your "N" drive is a mapped network drive then try switching to a location on your C drive.  Same for the file being read.